# JS and CSS files won't compress

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to compress my CSS and JS files in a Rails 3.1 application, without success.

The files won't get compressed.

Here is my *production.rb* file.

```
config.cache_classes                     = true
config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.serve_static_assets               = false
config.assets.compress                   = true
config.assets.compile                    = true
config.assets.js_compressor              = :closure
config.assets.css_compressor             = :yui
config.i18n.fallbacks                    = true
config.active_support.deprecation        = :notify
config.assets.digest                     = true
```

I've also tried to run `rake assets:precompile` without success.

Anyone knows what the problem may be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the source to the problem.
I had (for some reason) a manifest file inside the public dir that told the browser to fetch a non compress file.